# DoubleClick on a row in ListView

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Is there any possibility to get a value of doubleclicked row in ListView?
I registered an event:

```
    private void lvLista_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(lvLista.SelectedItems.ToString());
    }
```

But on message, when i doubleclick some row in listview i get:

> System.Windows.Forms.ListView+SelectedListViewItemCollection

What is more, I have got 2 columns in listview:

```
    lvLista.Columns.Add("ID");
    lvLista.Columns.Add("Tilte");
```

And i want to show in messagebox the "ID" of doubleclicked row. 
How to do it? How to get a values from this event?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try this:

```
private void lvLista_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    MessageBox.Show(lvLista.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[0].Text);
}
```

Comment: The (potential ) problem with this code is, what happens if the user clicks or double-clicks in an empty area of the list? In some cases, they may want whichever item was last selected to be the result. In other cases, though, they may want nothing to happen unless the user explicitly selects an item for the double-click.

Comment: I see I was at least a little wrong above. If the user double clicks on an empty area, the DoubleClick event doesn't fire. Very short-sighted of me (I've been using a different implementation which sets a member variable for use by other methods, so it was necessary to handle the case where nothing was clicked using the MouseDown Event).

Comment: This code has issue when you double click the checkbox on a row.

Comment: combine the ListViewHitTestInfo info = listView1.HitTest(e.X, e.Y); solution with this solution is what i did.

Answer (score 31):

If you handle the `MouseDown` and/or `MouseDoubleClick` events of the ListView control, and use the `HitTest` method to determine the target of the mouse action, you will know which item has been double clicked. This is also a good means to determine if NO item was clicked (for example, clicking on the empty area in a partially filled list.

The following code will display the clicked item in a textbox if a single click occurs, and will pop up a message box with the name of the double-clicked item if a double click occurs.

If the click or double click occur in an area of the list view not populated by an item, the text box or message box inform yopu of that fact.

This is a trivial example, and depending on your needs, you will have to mess with it a little.

UPDATE: I added some code which clears the SelectedItems property of the Listview control when an empty area of the list is clicked or double-clicked.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        listView1.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(listView1_MouseDown);
        listView1.MouseDoubleClick += new MouseEventHandler(listView1_MouseDoubleClick);
        this.Load += new EventHandler(Form1_Load);
    }


    void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.SetupListview();
    }


    private void SetupListview()
    {
        ListView lv = this.listView1;
        lv.View = View.List;


        lv.Items.Add("John Lennon");
        lv.Items.Add("Paul McCartney");
        lv.Items.Add("George Harrison");
        lv.Items.Add("Richard Starkey");
    }


    void listView1_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        ListViewHitTestInfo info = listView1.HitTest(e.X, e.Y);
        ListViewItem item = info.Item;

        if (item != null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("The selected Item Name is: " + item.Text);
        }
        else
        {
            this.listView1.SelectedItems.Clear();
            MessageBox.Show("No Item is selected");
        }
    }



    void listView1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        ListViewHitTestInfo info = listView1.HitTest(e.X, e.Y);
        ListViewItem item = info.Item;

        if (item != null)
        {
            this.textBox1.Text = item.Text;
        }
        else
        {
            this.listView1.SelectedItems.Clear();
            this.textBox1.Text = "No Item is Selected";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

I know this thread is old but nobody here answered the question properly in my opinion. For those in the future, try this, from [MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/022460b1-4164-4cd3-9efd-7afd92f5a17b/how-to-handle-onclick-event-of-listview?forum=vssmartdevicesvbcs):

```
// User must double-click to activate item
myListView.Activation = System.Windows.Forms.ItemActivation.Standard;

// Add event handler
myListView.ItemActivate += new 
System.EventHandler(this.myListView_ItemClick);
```

Comment: Although this works for double click, the event will also trigger if the item is clicked with two very distinct single clicks.

Comment: i think is the best solution

Comment: Setting Activation to TwoClick allows two distinct clicks, but Standard only allows double-click. I've updated the answer to use Standard.

Answer (score 3):

Since the accepted answer didn't help me i thought that I would share my solution to the same problem: getting data from a specific column in a listview in the double click event.

The following line returns the data of the second column in the row that I've double clicked on as a string:

```
private void listViewOutput_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   string content = listViewOutput.Items[listViewOutput.SelectedIndices[0]].SubItems[1].Text
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks; this is what I needed. I thought I'd also mention one could set up the local info variable more generally as:

```
  ListViewHitTestInfo info = ((ListView)sender).HitTest(e.X, e.Y);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
private void listView1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    ListViewHitTestInfo hit = listView1.HitTest(e.Location);

    Rectangle rowBounds = hit.SubItem.Bounds;
    Rectangle labelBounds = hit.Item.GetBounds(ItemBoundsPortion.Label);
    int leftMargin = labelBounds.Left - 1;

    string x = hit.Item.Text;

}
```