# How to simulate a file explorer using ListView in c#?

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

I'm pretty new to C# and Windows Form programming. I'd like to create a simple Windows Form which has a ListView initially populated with some items. Then, if I double click on an item I'd like to show some other sub-items. Apparently there will be a '...' item at the top which take me to the parent item. Can someone help me writing this simple windows form?

p.s. I'm not very familiar with C# Windows Form application architecture (Form.Designer.cs, Form1, Program.cs, etc)

Comment: Way too broad.  You really need to follow a tutorial if you are just starting out.

Comment: How are you doing with your file explorer do you need any help ? feel free to add some information so that I can adjust my answer

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the ListView you could populate it when you double Click a Directory.

What you need is

1. A double Click event
2. [DirectoryInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/System.IO.DirectoryInfo(v=VS.110).aspx)
3. [FileInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/System.IO.FileInfo(v=VS.110).aspx)

When programming a Windows Forms application you should consider dividing your business logic from your view logic keywords here are *Model view controller* or *Model View Presenter*.

**Lets begin**

I would create a DirectoryController class which handles some of your logic.
Your Forms class can handle the view logic then for example the double click event.

You could create a method which generates an ImageList so that you can use it in your ListView to have the correct Image for your File or Directory

```
private static ImageList GetFolderImageList()
{
    Image folderImg = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft-windows-printing-fdprint_31bf3856ad364e35_6.3.9600.17415_none_493b0b9e590044a1\folder.ico");
    ImageList imgList = new ImageList();
    imgList.Images.Add(folderImg);
    return imgList;
}
```

I used an Image from the Windows directory just so that this will initially work. But you can use an Image you want to show when having a directory in your ListView. By the way this will only demonstrate how to handle directories and not files, but from this point you should be able to handle files by yourself.

After you created the ImageList you can create Initialize the ListView.

```
    private void InitializeListView(ImageList imgList)
    {
        lvExplorer.DoubleClick += new System.EventHandler(this.lvExplorer_DoubleClick);
        lvExplorer.SmallImageList = imgList;
        lvExplorer.LargeImageList = imgList;
    }
```

My ListView is named lvExplorer and I added it already to the Windows Form in the designer. I used the Dockstyle to fill the whole form.

[image]

With this two functions you should be able to Initialize the ListView.

Now you need to populate the ListView.

```
private void ShowDirectoriesInListView(string path)
{
    DirectoryInfo info = new DirectoryInfo(path);

    DirectoryInfo parent = info.Parent;
    if (parent != null) 
    {
        lvExplorer.Items.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem("...", 0));
    }

    foreach (DirectoryInfo dInfo in info.GetDirectories())
    {
        lvExplorer.Items.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem(dInfo.Name, 0));
    }
}
```

With the ShowDirectoriesInListView method you can add your Directories to the ListView. The path parameter is the directory you want to show.
If the directory has a parent we add the "..." directory. A root directory normally has no parent so we won't add it then.

Now lets get to the point how we get the directory that we passed into the ShowDirectoriesInListView method.

As mentioned before we want to split view from business logic
So I created a controller class

```
class DirectoryController
{
    private string _currentDirectory;

    public DirectoryController(string beginDirectory) 
    {
        _currentDirectory = beginDirectory;
    }

    public string AddDirectoryAndGetPath(string path)
    {
        if (path.Equals("..."))
        {
            int lastIndex = _currentDirectory.Length;
            if (_currentDirectory.EndsWith(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar.ToString()))
            {
                lastIndex = _currentDirectory.LastIndexOf(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar);
                _currentDirectory = _currentDirectory.Remove(lastIndex);
            }
            lastIndex = _currentDirectory.LastIndexOf(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar) + 1;
            _currentDirectory = _currentDirectory.Remove(lastIndex);

        }
        else
        {
            _currentDirectory = string.Format("{0}{1}{2}", _currentDirectory, path, Path.DirectorySeparatorChar);
        }
        return _currentDirectory;
    }
}
```

The most important function of this class is the AddDirectoryAndGetPath method.
If the method gets a string with the contents "..." we remove the last directory name from our current directory otherwise we will add it.

Now coming back to the double click event.
You did set up a [Event handler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/aa645739(v=VS.71).aspx) in your InitializeListView method

The method which is called should have the same name as the method you passed as argument into the constructor of the EventHandler.

```
private void lvExplorer_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string path = lvExplorer.SelectedItems[0].Text;
    OpenDirectory(path);
}
```

When an item is double clicked the method is called and the SelectedItems list should be filled with one Item. I should mention here that it is possible that you have more than one item or none in the selectedItems array so please add some error handling into this method or set the `MultiSelect` property of the ListView to `false`.
The text property of the selected Item is filled with the directory name of the Item you clicked because we used the directory name in the `ShowDirectoriesInListView` method.

Afterwards the OpenDirectory method is called which clears the ListView and adds all the directories of the selected directory to it.

```
private void OpenDirectory(string path)
{
    try 
    {
        lvExplorer.Items.Clear();
        string newPath = _controller.AddDirectoryAndGetPath(path);
        ShowDirectoriesInListView(newPath);
    }
    catch (Exception ex) 
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

In the end you will have a Windows forms class like this

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
private DirectoryController _controller;

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    ImageList imgList = GetFolderImageList();
    InitializeListView(imgList);
    _controller = new DirectoryController("C:");
    OpenDirectory("");
}

private void InitializeListView(ImageList imgList)
{
    lvExplorer.DoubleClick += new System.EventHandler(this.lvExplorer_DoubleClick);
    lvExplorer.SmallImageList = imgList;
    lvExplorer.LargeImageList = imgList;
}

private static ImageList GetFolderImageList()
{
    Image folderImg = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft-windows-printing-fdprint_31bf3856ad364e35_6.3.9600.17415_none_493b0b9e590044a1\folder.ico");
    ImageList imgList = new ImageList();
    imgList.Images.Add(folderImg);
    return imgList;
}

private void lvExplorer_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string path = lvExplorer.SelectedItems[0].Text;
    OpenDirectory(path);
}

private void OpenDirectory(string path)
{
    try 
    {
        lvExplorer.Items.Clear();
        string newPath = _controller.AddDirectoryAndGetPath(path);
        ShowDirectoriesInListView(newPath);
    }
    catch (Exception ex) 
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}

private void ShowDirectoriesInListView(string path)
{
    DirectoryInfo info = new DirectoryInfo(path);

    DirectoryInfo parent = info.Parent;
    if (parent != null) 
    {
        lvExplorer.Items.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem("...", 0));
    }

    foreach (DirectoryInfo dInfo in info.GetDirectories())
    {
        lvExplorer.Items.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem(dInfo.Name, 0));
    }
}
}
```

From here on you should have the knowledge how to use the ListView and add your Files.

**SubItems**

If you want a detail view you could alter your InitializeListView method

```
private void InitializeListView(ImageList imgList)
{
    lvExplorer.DoubleClick += new System.EventHandler(this.lvExplorer_DoubleClick);
    lvExplorer.SmallImageList = imgList;
    lvExplorer.LargeImageList = imgList;
    CreateHeaders();
    lvExplorer.View = View.Details;
}

private void CreateHeaders()
{
    ColumnHeader header;

    header = new ColumnHeader();
    header.Text = "DirectoryName";
    lvExplorer.Columns.Add(header);

    header = new ColumnHeader();
    header.Text = "LastWriteTime";
    lvExplorer.Columns.Add(header);
}
```

We create here two header columns and set the View property of our ListView to Details.

If you now add subItems to your `ShowDirectoriesInListView` method you have a very nice detail view of your directories.

```
private void ShowDirectoriesInListView(string path)
{
    DirectoryInfo info = new DirectoryInfo(path);

    DirectoryInfo parent = info.Parent;
    if (parent != null) 
    {
        lvExplorer.Items.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem("...", 0));
    }

    foreach (DirectoryInfo dInfo in info.GetDirectories())
    {
        ListViewItem item = new System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem(dInfo.Name, 0);
        item.Tag = dInfo.Name;

        //Add some subitems here
        System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem subItem = new ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem();
        subItem.Text = dInfo.LastWriteTime.ToShortDateString();
        item.SubItems.Add(subItem); 
        lvExplorer.Items.Add(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

These sub-items (listed in the ListViewItem.SubItems collection) are a bit confusing, if you are using a ListView for the first time. The items represent the first column of your ListView, where as the sub-items represent the columns to the right. So the sub-items are not, as you could think, the sub-directories you might have in mind.

This post shows you how you can handle the double click event on a item: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12874269/880990

Look into the `DirectoryInfo` and `FileInfo` classes of the `System.IO` namespace for file operations.